# How can I validate a collection of string and each element as a URL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, annotations

I want to validate URLs in a `Collection<String>`. Each element is a URL that I get as a string in the form.

```
@Valid
@URL
@ElementCollection 
public Collection<String> getPictures() {       
    return this.pictures;   
}

public void setPictures(final Collection<String> pictures) {         
      this.pictures = pictures;     
}
```

I want to know if there is some annotation in Spring that allows me to validate all the strings in this collection like URLs

Comment: There is no direct and straight forward annotation, you can use Hibernate validation framework and you can create your own annotations to validate fields/classes etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no annotation that validates the field directly. The idea of a custom annotation `@URL` is perfectly valid, yet you have to implement the validation itself - the annotation is just a mark that "something should happen with this".

I suggest you rename `@URL` to `@URLCollection` to avoid conflict with the class [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). Start with defining the annotation. Don't forget to the annotation [`@Constraint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Constraint.html) (look at its documentation to learn how to define the custom validation annotation properly):

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UrlCollectionValidator.class)     // will be created below
public @interface URLCollection {
    String message() default "default error message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then continue with the implementation of [`ConstraintValidator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html):

```
public class UrlCollectionValidator implements ConstraintValidator<URLCollection, Collection<String>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URLCollectionconstraint) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Collection<String> urls, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return // the validation logics
    }
}
```

Well, that's all. Read more about this at [Configuring Custom Constraints](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints) at the Spring documentation:

> Each bean validation constraint consists of two parts: * A `@Constraint` annotation that declares the constraint and its configurable properties. * An implementation of the `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` interface that implements the constraint’s behavior.

Comment: in this particular case, @URL seems to be org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL rather than a custom annotation. Just like org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email, which has been deprecated in favour of javax.validation.constraints.Email, btw.